# Javascript open page with variable to open tab of tabbed section

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was looking for a solution to have a certain tab open when page was viewed by Url Parameter.
I have seen a few examples but they do not seem to work. Maybe they are to old to work with current javascript.
Here is what I have found:

```
var tabName = (window.location.href.match(/[?&]tab-name=[^&$]+/i) || '=').split('=')[1];
tabName='profile'; // remove this line on real page
if(tabName.length)
$('#myTabs .nav-link[href="#' + tabName + '"]').tab('show');
```

The above works fine with the // remove this line on real page - in place. once that is taken out and it relies on the varible. Console window says `(window.location.href.match(/[?&]tab-name=[^&$]+/i) || '=').split('=')[1];` is not a correct function.

I have this and it does not seem to work either. It gets the parameter but it still needs stripped to get just the parameter to open the tab.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const params = Object.fromEntries(urlSearchParams.entries());
    var tabName = params;
    if (tabName.length)
        $('#myTabs .nav-link[href="#' + tabName + '"]').tab('show');
    debugger
});
```

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by doing it this way..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    let params = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search.substring(1));
    let name = params.get("name");
    if (name.length)
        $('#myTabs .nav-link[href="#' + name + '"]').tab('show');
    //debugger
});
```

URL is `myAddress.com/Profile?name=settings`
Weird, when I used the word `tabName` this didn't work but `name` does..